# getting wrong data after scrolling listview in android

Tags: android

I am getting wrong data after scrolling listview,after scrolling images are show on another listitem.

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<ContactBean> contactDataList;
private ArrayList<ContactBean> arraylist;
Context context;
ViewHolder v;

public ContactListAdapter(List<ContactBean> contactBeans, Context context) {
    contactDataList = contactBeans;
    this.context = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(contactDataList);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactDataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return contactDataList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
    }

    v = new ViewHolder();

    v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
    v.imageView = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    v.firstChar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstChae);

    final ContactBean data = contactDataList.get(i);
    v.title.setText(contactDataList.get(i).getName());
    v.phone.setText(contactDataList.get(i).getPhone());


    // Set image if exists
    try {
        if (contactDataList.get(i).getThumb() != null) {
            v.firstChar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
        } else {
            v.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String headerChar = (String) contactDataList.get(i).getName().subSequence(0, 1);
            v.firstChar.setText(headerChar);
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // Add default picture
        //  v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this.context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + contactDataList.get(i).getThumb());
    view.setTag(data);
    return view;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    RoundedImageView imageView;
    TextView title, phone, firstChar;
}
}
```

in my contact list some contacts having image and which one not having a image thst show the first letter of initialletter of contact name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Zf3.png)
run the app i am geting this but scroool the listview the we get[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzmDy.png)

Comment: could you add more information about how its wrong, are only the ones that normally don't have images getting wring images? Or are the images mixed up between the ones that should have images? Or are they all mixed up independent if they should or shouldn't have an image?

Comment: i am create a custom contact loader so show the the contact name ,phone no,and image or suppose image in not available so show the initial letter of name,all are show right  but scrolling the list view that i am getting wrong image in another contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

UPD:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<ContactBean> contactBeans;
    private Context context;

    public ContactListAdapter(List<ContactBean> contactBeans, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactBeans = contactBeans;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactBeans.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return contactBeans.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder v;

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            v = new ViewHolder();
            v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
            v.imageView = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
            v.firstChar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstChae);
            view.setTag(v);
        }

        v = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        final ContactBean data = contactBeans.get(i);

        v.title.setText(data.getName());
        v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());


        // Set image if exists
        try {
            if (data.getThumb() != null) {
                v.firstChar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                v.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
            } else {
                v.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String headerChar = (String) data.getName().subSequence(0, 1);
                v.firstChar.setText(headerChar);
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // Add default picture
            //  v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this.context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + data.getThumb());
        return view;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        RoundedImageView imageView;
        TextView title, phone, firstChar;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You. Its Working @mit

Answer (score 0):

You should only initialize your viewHolder once, and thats when your convertView is null. Place this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
    v = new ViewHolder();
    convertView.setTag(v);
} else {
    v = convertView.getTag();
}
```

Check this link for better understanding. It's from Google. Starts at about minute 6:00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

Remove the global ViewHolder

`ViewHolder v;`

The scope of ViewHolder instance have to be inside the getView method only not whole adapter.

Replace the

```
v = new ViewHolder();
```

with

```
ViewHolder v = new ViewHolder();
```

here i cannot find any use of viewHolder actually,
you can simply try like this

```
 public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
        RoundedImageView imageView = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        TextView firstChar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstChae);

        final ContactBean data = contactDataList.get(i);
        title.setText(contactDataList.get(i).getName());
        phone.setText(contactDataList.get(i).getPhone());


        // Set image if exists
        try {
            if (contactDataList.get(i).getThumb() != null) {
                firstChar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
            } else {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String headerChar = (String) contactDataList.get(i).getName().subSequence(0, 1);
                firstChar.setText(headerChar);
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // Add default picture
            //  v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this.context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + contactDataList.get(i).getThumb());
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your simply missing to set the character visible, due to it possibly being invisible from being recycled.

The correct code (containing Ricardo Barroca's improvment):

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<ContactBean> contactDataList;
private ArrayList<ContactBean> arraylist;
Context context;
ViewHolder v;

public ContactListAdapter(List<ContactBean> contactBeans, Context context) {
    contactDataList = contactBeans;
    this.context = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(contactDataList);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactDataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return contactDataList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
        v = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(v);
    } else {
        v = convertView.getTag();
    }
    View view = convertView;

    v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
    v.imageView = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    v.firstChar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstChae);

    final ContactBean data = contactDataList.get(i);
    v.title.setText(contactDataList.get(i).getName());
    v.phone.setText(contactDataList.get(i).getPhone());


    // Set image if exists
    try {
        if (contactDataList.get(i).getThumb() != null) {
            v.firstChar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
        } else {
            v.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String headerChar = (String) contactDataList.get(i).getName().subSequence(0, 1);
            v.firstChar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.firstChar.setText(headerChar);
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // Add default picture
        //  v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this.context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + contactDataList.get(i).getThumb());
    view.setTag(data);
    return view;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    RoundedImageView imageView;
    TextView title, phone, firstChar;
}
}
```